# The remote server returned an error (403) forbidden. Error?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble downloading the file, here's the link:

```
http://vsbg023.cda.pl/apple/13801451161599.mp4?st=zFHkNA18rmxan4AvOQWRmw&e=1431286721
```

(This is just an example)

As soon as the WebClient tries to download it, it raises the exception "The remote server returned an error ( 403 ) forbidden"

I searched in google, I only found this: http://pastebin.com/arU4WtC7

But nothing gives this error, sometimes it starts to download, but only for a while and the program is suspended, even though the file is still downloading.

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?

You can download the code here:
http://pastebin.com/w67Rxikh

Comment: As I don't have any information where you get the download link from I can just guess that you need to set some cookies or so on.

Comment: You asked the same question 15 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156635/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-403-forbidden

Comment: http://www.cda.pl/video/2146342f/Avengers-Age-of-Ultron-_2015_-ENG-CAM in source code find mp4 link to download http://vsbg003.cda.pl/fb490a07f5da3acfb3cd7857f6e2dba6.mp4?st=p6tRJRDE-TxhuZ4_H1awOw&e=1431360825